# mod_wsgi 4.3 on Windows?

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-wsgi

at work we have an apache server and the security guys want me to update the mod_wsgi from 3.5 to 4.3, because they are getting security issue mails beacause of that mod. Problem is, that the 3.5 version is the latest version for window, according to http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/release-notes/version-4.3.0.html. Directly install it into python does not work on windows and as far as I have read, it is not recommended to update to 4.x. 
Has anybody found a 4.3 build somewhere, that I could install without any problems?
I actually don't have the knowledge or time to write the makefiles myself...

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Actually, I just asked how I can update a windows apache from mod_wsgi 3.5 to 4.3, as there is no version for windows from 3.5+ I just explained why I need to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.5 of mod_wsgi has back ported versions of the security fixes. You can still safely use that on Windows.

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/05/security-release-for-modwsgi-version-35.html
- http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

Comment: so you are actually saying, that there is indeed no 4.x version for windows?

Comment: Correct. At this time there is no Windows version of mod_wsgi 4.X. The issue is merely a lack of updated makefiles to build it on Windows. I don't have access to Windows to be able to update them myself to cope with the fact that the code is now split across many files and not just one anymore. The code files are also now in a sub directory and not the top level directory. No one has stepped up who is willing to do the work to help me out. As I said though, the critical security fixes were back ported to version 3.5 and there are binaries for Windows for that version, so use version 3.5.